# Load Data Local Infile only Loads values from first column of csv file

Tags: mysql, bash, csv, load-data-infile

I am trying to import a big csv file into mysql via bash command line.

```
mysql -u root --password=password -e \
"CREATE DATABASE library; \
USE library; \
CREATE TABLE books (id INT NOT NULL, \
id2 INT NOT NULL, \
id3 INT NOT NULL, \
name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id)); \
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'books.csv' \
INTO TABLE books FIELDS TERMINATED by '\t' \
ENCLOSED BY '\'' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES \
(id,id2,id3,name)"
```

this is the csv file
(This is just part of the csv file the original has over 600 lines)

```
+----+-----+-----+----------------------
| id | id3 | id4 |  name 
+----+-----+-----+----------------------
|  2 |  3  |  4  |  harry potter 
|  1 |  9  |  5  |  spiderwicks
|  4 |  7  |  6  |  attack on titan
|  5 |  2  |  1  |  the roots 
|  3 |  8  |  1  |  wrecking ball 
|  6 |  4  |  1  |  luther vandross
```

When i run the sql command above in the bash terminal i get no errors. However no every columns is populated correctly. When I check the contents of the table with `SELECT * FROM books;`, this is what I get:

```
+----+-----+-----+------+
| id | id3 | id4 | name |
+----+-----+-----+------+
| 2  | 0   | 0   |      |
| 1  | 0   | 0   |      |
| 4  | 0   | 0   |      |
| 5  | 0   | 0   |      |
| 3  | 0   | 0   |      |
| 6  | 0   | 0   |      |
```

The columns id3 and id4 have the value 0 and the column name doesn't even have any value.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does your CSV file looks *exactly* like what you showed?

Comment: not excactly it has over 600 lines, but the first 6 lines look like that

Comment: The way you used the command you specified that the fields in your `books.csv` file are separated by `tab` character and enclosed with `'`. Check if your file really has this structure and update your code if necessary.